# Symfony mandatory parameters missing

Tags: php, symfony, url, routes

I am using the Symfony form component to display an edit form to the user (for editing a question).

When clicking on the edit button, I use this function in my controller to render the edit form:

```
/**
 * Display edit form
 * @Route("/edit/question/{id}", name="app_question_edit", methods={"GET"})
 * @param Question $question
 * @return Response
 */
public function edit(Question $question): Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(QuestionFormType::class, $question);
    
    return $this->render('question/edit.html.twig',[
        'questionEditForm' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

So, an exemplary url would be "**/edit/question/1**"

The form action is a PUT request to another route (set like this in the twig template):

```
<div class="container mt-2" id="one-question">
      {{ form_start(questionEditForm, {'action': path('app_question_update'), 'method': 'PUT'}) }}
      {{ form_widget(questionEditForm) }}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary edit-question-btn mt-2">
         Update
      </button>
      {{ form_end(questionEditForm) }}
   </div>
```

And I am using another function in my controller to process the request (**yes this is not best practice, I am just playing around**).

```
    /**
     * @Route("/questions/{slug}", name="app_question_update", methods={"PUT"})
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Question $question
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
     * @return RedirectResponse
     */
    public function update(Question $question, Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): RedirectResponse
    {
        dd($question);
        // ...
    }
```

In order to update the right question, I need the question.
So I though with passing the `Question $question`, Symfony would use the id found in the slug to do a "findOneBy" (instead of passing the id directly etc).

But I get the following error:

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Some mandatory parameters are missing ("id") to generate a URL for route "app_question_update".").

When I remove the slug & the Question $question param, the form is rendered and when I dd the request after submission I can see the form data as well, but I am lacking the question id + I want to get this to work with the slug.

Comment: You'll need to pass the `slug` parameter yourself to the `path()` function in the form action. You could maybe get it from `questionEditForm.vars` so you don't have to pass additional objects to your view.

Comment: Ah, I think I am getting the hang of it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the `{slug}` parameter to the path() function in you twig template:

```
{{ path('app_question_update', {slug: quetionId}) }}
```

But before that you have to pass the `questionId` to the view in you Edit Controller:

```
    return $this->render('question/edit.html.twig',[
        'questionEditForm' => $form->createView(),
        'questionId' => $question->getId()
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `slug` parameter in the path method in the twig

```
{{ form_start(questionEditForm, {'action': path('app_question_update', {slug: questionEditForm.vars.value.slug}), 'method': 'PUT'}) }}
```